# ACCIDENTALLY ISSUED DD COMMAND AGAINST EXTERNAL HDD

Tags: external-hdd, dd, testdisk, exfat

I recently issued **dd if=/home of=/dev/sdb** and turned out to ruin the `exfat filesystem` on my external `harddrive`. I immediately issued **ctrl-c** to stop writing.

Read few threads indicating the use of `testdisk`. Used it, found about 8 partitions while the drive was only set up for 1, namely /dev/sdb1.

Committed the partitions, writing it via Testdisk. Also listed via 'p' option, to peek into each, but files was not seen.

I downloaded a live disc for disc rescue purposes, and it found almost all my files, but needs a license to use. So it appears 'everything' is still there.

Herewith output **'sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb'**

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9325805F-4271-3E4D-B69D-C47688A019CE

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      264192  409864183  409599992 195.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2   506238524  506244283       5760   2.8M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3   802104892  802110651       5760   2.8M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  1333559296 1333952225     392930 191.9M Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdb5  1337229312 1337622241     392930 191.9M Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdb6  1469117799 2476602728 1007484930 480.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb7  3038125628 3038131387       5760   2.8M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb8   409864184  506238523   96374340    46G Linux filesystem

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Command (m for help): m
```

Also, **Testdisk** output.

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 3000 GB / 2794 GiB - CHS 364801 255 63

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
> 1 P MS Data                   264192  409864183  409599992 [exfat]
  8 P Unknown                409864184  506238523   96374340 [264192s]
  2 P MS Data                506238524  506244283       5760 [NO NAME]
  3 P MS Data                802104892  802110651       5760 [NO NAME]
  4 P Mac HFS               1333559296 1333952225     392930 [VTC33257]
  5 P Mac HFS               1337229312 1337622241     392930 [VTC33257]
  6 P MS Data               1469117799 2476602728 1007484930
  7 P MS Data               3038125628 3038131387       5760 [NO NAME]
```

I am facing obtacles fixing this in linux, that or I am missing something.

I have seen mention of using `parted`. I.e. `mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END`.

Attempts to mount what testdisk 'wrote', I get complaints like bad superblock etc.

If someone can please assist. My suspicion is that Windows would be needed here since its exfat, but I already tried, and it didnt show up in windows, so back at Linux.

Comment: There are some data recovery tools for Windows, that might be better.  Some cost but some are free, google to find and compare.  Usually should use Linux to fix Linux and Windows to fix Windows for best results.

Comment: gparted has a data recovery tool built in, iy is VERY slow and I doubt you will get much back. Sorry to say.